# Unit Test case for Generic HttpGet methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How can I write test cases for Generic Http methods. My methods are below.

```
    public async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(string urlSuffix)
    {
        var url = Common.FormatUrl(urlSuffix, _instanceUrl, _apiVersion);
        return await HttpGetAsync<T>(url);
    }

    public async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(Uri uri)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await HttpGetAsync(uri);
            var jToken = JToken.Parse(response);
            if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                var jArray = JArray.Parse(response);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jArray.ToString());
            }
            // else
            try
            {
                var jObject = JObject.Parse(response);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jObject.ToString());
            }
            catch
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
            }
        }
        catch (BaseHttpClientException e)
        {
            throw ParseForceException(e.Message);
        }
    }

 protected async Task<string> HttpGetAsync(Uri uri)
{
  var responseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
  if (responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
  {
    return string.Empty;
  }

  var response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    return response;
  }

  throw new BaseHttpClientException(response, responseMessage.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: Horrible exception "handling", BTW.

Comment: Why are you parsing, then detecting the token type, then parsing again, then converting to a string, then parsing for a third time? I suspect you just want to call `JToken.ToObject<T>` after parsing as a token...

Comment: @JonSkeet Not much I can do, legacy code. Just trying to add a unit test to legacy code

Comment: Well once you've got the test, you can can presumably change the implementation - I'm not suggesting changing the *result*, just the implementation...

Comment: It looks like you've missed a method though - the non-generic method that returns the string...

Comment: @JonSkeet Which line you're talking about?

Comment: `var response = await HttpGetAsync(uri);` - what's that calling? You haven't shown the method that calls...

Comment: @JonSkeet updated that method too.

Comment: Right. So *one* option for unit testing this code is to make that method virtual. You can then make a fake subclass that returns whatever string you want it to. Alternatively, you could create an `HttpClient` with a custom `HttpClientHandler` to avoid making actual requests, instead returning precanned data.